# Updating Linux fot Tegra version on Jetson TX2

Tags: nvidia-jetson

I am trying to update my Linux from Tegra version from 32.2.1 to 32.7.4 on my Jetson TX2.

I'm following the following guide on the part "To upgrade to a new minor release" fond here:

https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/archives/l4t-archived/l4t-325/index.html#page/Tegra%20Linux%20Driver%20Package%20Development%20Guide/updating_jetson_and_host.html#wwpID0E0PB0HA

Following the guide i updated my "nvidia-l4t-apt-source.list" to:

````
deb https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r32.7 main
deb https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t186 r32.7 main```
````

But when I run "sudo apt-get update" I have the following error:

```
Err:1 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r32.7 InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0D296FFB880FB004
Hit:10 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:4 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t186 r32.7 InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0D296FFB880FB004
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r32.7 InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0D296FFB880FB004
E: The repository 'https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r32.7 InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
W: GPG error: https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t186 r32.7 InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0D296FFB880FB004
E: The repository 'https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t186 r32.7 InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```